# How to get resource object in RCP App

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I use CNF to make a view like Project Explorer in my RCP app. I'm done showing new menu and its submenu when user right clicks on a project in the view.
[image]

But when user click on a submenu (for this case, a method library going to be created), **I need to know which project object that user has right-clicked on**.

My question is how can I do that? Please help me.

Thank you all,
Nautilus

Answer (score 0):

I think the wiki page [E4/EAS/Selection](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/EAS/Selection) should provide a way to query the right selection.

> In Eclipse 3.x, the org.eclipse.ui.ISelectionService allows workbench parts to query the active selection in addition to attaching listeners for monitoring selection changes.

(see [this example](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/183768/))

In the e4 world, selection is propagated with the `ESelectionService`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank VonC,

Now I got the resource object that user has right-clicked on by doing this:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
    CommonNavigator view = (CommonNavigator)page.findView("spe.ui.navigator.view");
    selection = (IStructuredSelection) view.getSite().getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
```

But I'm really not happy completely with the solution. Note that I open a INewWizard after the action. In the INewWizard we have `public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection)`. I really want to use this method but I don't how to make it work.

Please, someone help me.
Thanks

Comment: Don't you get the selected resources in your `IStructuredSelection selection` parameter of the `init` method?

Comment: No, I don't. The `init` method even has not been invoked. I've not configured the wizard in `plugin.xml`, I've called it programmatically.